# Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded - socket.io

Tags: javascript, node.js, websocket, socket.io

I've been getting this error when more than 1 person has an active websocket connection.

In io.on('connection') I have io.on('disconnect'):

```
socket.on('disconnect', function(m) {
    var address = socket.client.request.headers['x-forwarded-for'] || socket.request.connection.remoteAddress;
   if(usersOnline[address])
    {
      delete usersOnline[address];
    }
    io.sockets.emit('message', {
      type: 'connections',
      total: Object.keys(usersOnline).length
    });

});
```

And I'm calling the connect() function which has emit('disconnect') in it when the document is ready:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    connect();
```

The disconnect handler in the connect() function:

```
SOCKET.on('disconnect', function(m) {
            SOCKET.emit('disconnect', {
                hash: hash
            });
        });
```

When removing the handler (or on('disconnect')), I get "Websocket is closed before the connection is established...

What can I do to fix this problem? I've been researching for over a week now, and other Stackoverflow posts regarding a similar issue haven't helped so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue got fixed by updating socket.io to 2.0...

*facepalm*